# Makefile cutting out variables in for loop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing my first complex Makefile for a highly-modularized project.

I have various sub-directories, each one has its own Makefile which supports at least the `all` and the `clean` targets.

These sub-Makefiles work just fine, however I have a problem with the main Makefile, that should call all the sub-Makefiles automatically from the list contained in the variable `COMPONENTS`.

I tried with the following Makefile:

```
OUTFILE = diskimage.bin

export NASM = nasm

COMPONENTS = bootloader

.PHONY = all clean FORCE $(OUTFILE) $(COMPONENTS)

all: $(OUTFILE)

$(OUTFILE): $(COMPONENTS)
    ./make_image

$(COMPONENTS): FORCE
    for component in $(COMPONENTS); do \
        make -C $component; \
    done

FORCE:

clean:
    for component in $(COMPONENTS); do \
        make -C $component clean; \
    done
```

This results in the following error message:

```
for component in bootloader; do \
                make -C omponent; \
        done
make: *** omponent: No such file or directory. Stop.
make: *** [bootloader] Error 2
```

as if the `$component` expression was only parsed as `$c`. I don't understand why that happens and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues.

- `.PHONY` should be written as a dependency, not a macro definition
- Don't write shell loops, use *make* syntax instead
- When you call *make* recursively, you must do it via the `${MAKE}` macro invocation

Leading to

```
OUTFILE = diskimage.bin
export NASM = nasm
COMPONENTS = bootloader

.PHONY: all
all: ${OUTFILE}

.PHONY: ${OUTFILE}
${OUTFILE}: ${COMPONENTS}
    ./make_image

.PHONY: ${COMPONENTS}
${COMPONENTS}:
    ${MAKE} -C $@
```

The advantage of this formulation is that it is parallel *make* friendly.
Always a test of a good Makefile.
Here `make -j5 all` will cause *make* to keep 5 commands running at once,
across all invocations of *make*.
Nice if you have 4 CPUs.

What about *clean*?
(Personally I hate *clean* targets—it's a sign of dodgy dependencies,
and of unhygienic mixing of source and target folders.)

Just add `-clean` (say) to each of the component names,
and repeat the pattern above.

```
CLEANS := $(addsuxffix -clean,${COMPONENTS})

.PHONY: clean
clean: ${CLEANS} ; @echo Clean succesful

.PHONY: ${CLEANS}
${CLEANS}: %-clean:
    ${MAKE} -C $* clean
```

These two sections can tidied up and combined into one if you feel so inclined.

**Tip**

*Always* run *make* with `--warn` (or `--warn-undefined-variables` to give it its full name) to catch inadvertent expansion of `$c` in things like `$component`.

Answer (score 2):

Just double the dollar sign:

```
$(COMPONENTS): FORCE
    for component in $(COMPONENTS); do \
  make -C $$component; \
  done
```

The trouble is that with your makefile, Make expands `$component` before executing the rule. And since `$c` has no value (there is no such variable), it expands to nothing, leaving "omponent", which it passes to she shell, which complains that there's no such directory. (If you had written `$(component)`, Make would have expanded it to nothing, since Make knows of no such variable, and then the shell would have complained that you were not specifying a directory at all.)

With the double dollar sign, Make expands `$$component` to `$component`, which it then passes to the shell, which interprets it as the loop variable, and everything proceeds as planned.

You really should have played around with a simple loop in a command, before attempting to do actual work with one.

Comment: Ok - I see where I failed to understand: I didn't really get that the for loop was executed by the shell and not by make. But it makes sense now that I think of it, and the backslashes should definitely have been a big clue. $$ is expanded into $ by make, which then, of course, results in valid shell syntax. Coming from a Windows environment, I'm not used to such a degree of integration between different software.